# Remove files when first two characters are ZZ

Tags: windows, powershell, desktop

I want to delete all the files when the first two characters are equal to `zz` or `ZZ`. How can I do it?

Comment: NTFS is not case sensitive, so del zz* removes files even if name begins with zz, zZ, Zz or ZZ.

Comment: that doesn't works because the zz files are in diffrent subfolders

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Get all objects (including hidden, recursively) from a path with names starting with 'zz', filter out directory objects and delete the items.

```
Get-ChildItem <path> -Recurse -Force -Filter zz* | Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer} | Remove-Item
```

Comment: to avoid the Where-Object checking for non containers just use the -File parameter to Get-ChildItem 
`Get-ChildItem <path> -Recurse -File -Force -Filter zz* | Remove-Item`

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
Remove-Item zz*
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, easy and quick, you can do it with anything even put extensions just using the wildcard with `Remove-Item *.js`, amazing!

Answer (score 0):

```
get-childitem zz* |
  where-object {$_ -cmatch "^(zz|ZZ)"} |
   foreach-item {remove-item $_.fullname}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's faster with -filter.  Take off the -whatif when you're sure it's what you want.

```
get-childitem -recurse -file -filter zz* | remove-item -whatIf
```

Answer (score -1):

NSFileManager *FileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *Paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

//Faccio la dir dei file *.txt da preparare 
NSDirectoryEnumerator *DirFile = [FileManager enumeratorAtPath:[Paths objectAtIndex:0]];

IFileTxt = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSString *file;
while ((file = [DirFile nextObject])) {

```
//In your case you need to test substring = "ZZ"
if ([[file pathExtension] isEqualToString: @"txt"]){ 
    [FileManager removeItemAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",[Paths objectAtIndex:0],file] error:nil];
}
```

}

[IFileTxt release];